# What is representer theorem?

Tags: kernel-trick

Representer theorem states that "a minimizer of a regularized empirical risk functional defined over a reproducing kernel Hilbert space can be represented as a finite linear combination of kernel products evaluated on the input points in the training set data".

What would be a simple explanation/derivation of the representer theorem? I do also see the connection with the kernel trick but not sure about the details. I have checked several sources but I could not get a grasp of the theorem.